# UIImageView animation and retina images

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm using the following code to animate my company logo in the app main screen:

```
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_001.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_002.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_003.png"],
                      nil];

    self.imageViewLogo.image = [array lastObject];
    self.imageViewLogo.animationImages = array;
    self.imageViewLogo.animationDuration = 1;
    self.imageViewLogo.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    [self.imageViewLogo startAnimating];
```

How should I deal with the retina @2x images in this case?

Comment: iOS will automatically use the @2x if you have the image named right. i.e logo_01 and logo_01@2x. Also, you dont need to put .png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have retina images:

```
logo_001@2x.png
logo_002@2x.png
logo_003@2x.png
```

You don't need to do anything. `[UIImage imageNamed:]` will return the original image for non-retina devices and the 2x image for retina devices.